# Use object property values of two JS array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays

```
let arr1 = [{'id': 'ee', 'seat': '12'}, 
  {'id': 'aa', 'seat': '8'}
]
let arr2 = [
  {'id': 's22', 'num': ''}, 
  {'id': '2s2', 'num': ''}
]
```

I want to copy seat values from arr1 to num property at arr2, but I only get last arr1 seat value in for loop.

```
for( let i = 0; i <= arr1.length; i++) {
  for( let x = 0; x <= arr2.length; x++) {
    arr2[x]['num'] = arr1[i]['seat'];
  }
}

console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use nested loops, currently you begin with setting every num of your second array to the first seat of the first array, then carry on setting every num of your second array to the second seat of the first array. You haven't described what the association between the first array and second array elements should be, so it's not currently possible to provide you with a specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate `arr2` with `Array.forEach()`, and take the respective `seat` value by index from `arr1`:

```js
const arr1 = [{'id': 'ee', 'seat': '12'},{'id': 'aa', 'seat': '8'}]
const arr2 = [{'id': 's22', 'num': ''},{'id': '2s2', 'num': ''}]

arr2.forEach((o, i) => o.num = arr1[i].seat)

console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need just a single loop and check if the index of the array if is (only) **smaller** than the length of the minimum of both arrays.

If the index get the length of an array, the access returns `undefined`, because this element is not in the array.

A further access to a property of this throws an error:

> ```
> Unable to get property 'seat' of undefined or null reference
> ```

```js
var arr1 = [{ id: 'ee', seat: '12' }, { id: 'aa', seat: '8' }],
    arr2 = [{ id: 's22', num: '' }, { id: '2s2', num: '' }],
    i, l;

for (i = 0, l = Math.min(arr1.length, arr2.length); i < l; i++) {
    arr2[i].num = arr1[i].seat;
}

console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in just one for loop.

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arr2[i].num = arr1[i].seat;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you want to match indices, this should do it.

```js
const arr1 = [
  {'id': 'ee', 'seat': '12'}, 
  {'id': 'aa', 'seat': '8'}
]
const arr2 = [
  {'id': 's22', 'num': ''}, 
  {'id': '2s2', 'num': ''}
]

const result = arr2.map((e, i) => ({...e, ...{num: arr1[i].seat}}))

console.log(result)
```

If you want all of the `seat`s in each `num`, it wouldn't be much harder.